I am trying to put a ceiling in an 18x25 room, what is the best way to put up ceiling joist when I only have 16ft lumber in my area?
I have an 18x25 room I'm building inside an existing shop but wanting to insulate this area, I want to put in a ceiling for the joist i was thinking of building a beam consisting of 3 2x10 and 2 3/4" osb. i would install the beam across the center of the 25' wall  leaving me to be able to put 12.5 foot 2x8 off either side 16" o.c. for the ceiling joist. is this the correct way to go about this or am I missing something?


You might be able to build your own composite beam across the middle, with two 16' pieces sistered together, and a cut in half 8' piece to fill out the ends.  There will be no loads here, other than the weight of the drywall and insulation?

correct no load ceiling

Do you have a cross section of your proposed beam?  I'm having trouble understanding where the OSB comes in.
